# Run simple programme using unix shell

Tags: shell, unix, environment-variables

I'm new to unix and its developing. In my `new.sh` script I wrote

```
$USERNAME=user
$PASSWORD=sekrit

echo $USERNAME
```

and ran `new.sh` using `bash new.sh`

But I get the following errors

```
new.sh: line 1: =user: command not found
new.sh: line 2: =sekrit: command not found
```

How do I run that command and print the username variable in terminal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`USERNAME` is the name of the variable. `$USERNAME` is the replacement (aka contents, aka value). Since `USERNAME` is empty, you effectively try to run a command named `=user`, which is what the error message tells you.

Remove the $ from `$USERNAME=...` and it will work.

Comment: Jens thank you it works. Now i know how to use local variables in the unix script

Answer (score 1):

As [Jens](https://stackoverflow.com/users/648658/jens) notes in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28346971/15168), the problem is that an assignment to a variable is not prefixed with a `$`, so:

```
USERNAME=user
PASSWORD=sekrit
```

is the way to write what you wanted.  You got an error because USERNAME was not set, so after expansion, the shell looked at the command as:

```
=user
=sekrit
```

and it could not find such commands on the system (not very surprisingly).  However, be aware that if you have previously written:

```
USERNAME=archipelago
PASSWORD=anchovy
```

then the lines:

```
$USERNAME=user
$PASSWORD=sekrit
```

would have been equivalent to writing:

```
archipelago=user
anchovy=sekrit
```

You could see that by running `set` with no arguments; it would show you the values of all the variables set in the shell.  You could search for words such as USERNAME and archipelago to see what happened.

Now you've learned that, forget it.  The number of times you'll need to use it is very limited (but it is handy on those rare — very rare — occasions when you need it).

For all practical purposes, don't write a `$` on the left-hand side of a variable assignment in shell.

Comment: You're welcome.  You might note that even where you watch TV programmes (for example, in Britain, and maybe other areas influenced by Britain rather than America), it is conventional to use 'program' for a computer program.